# Can I load multiple csv files using pyarrow?

Tags: python, csv, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am aware that this can be done in R as follows

```
ds <- open_dataset("nyc-taxi/csv/2019", format = "csv",
  partitioning = "month")
```

But is there a way to do in python ? Tried these but seems like thats not an option

```
from pyarrow import csv
table = csv.read_csv("*.csv")
```

```
from pyarrow import csv
path = os.getcwd()
table = csv.read_csv(path)
table
```

Is there a way to make it happen in python ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with pyarrow as well, similarly as in R, using the `pyarrow.dataset` submodule (the `pyarrow.csv` submodule only exposes functionality for dealing with single csv files).

Example code:

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

dataset = ds.dataset("nyc-taxi/csv/2019", format="csv", partitioning=["month"])
table = dataset.to_table()
```

And then in the `to_table()` method you can specify row/column filters.

Comment: Great! I want to convert it to a parquet file format, so can I convert it from dataset ? or should I make it a table before writing to parquet? my understanding is when we convert it to table takes time as deserializing is involved.

Comment: You can directly write the dataset to parquet without first converting to a Table (now, in practice, the CSV will still need to be deserialized and read as a table in order to write as parquet). Writing the dataset to Parquet can be done with `ds.write_dataset(dataset, format="parquet")`

Comment: But it does not work with 'csv.gz' collections.